# GWT clickHandler - Condition failing

Tags: java, gwt

I have a click handler method defined in a class. I am trying to call a particular method if a cancel button on the screen is clicked. 
here's the code snippet -

```
    boolean tempCheck;

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {

    super.onBind();

    ...
    ...

    getViewName().getVar().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {

    //Doing some operation and making tempCheck true

    tempCheck = true;       

    }
    });


    If(tempCheck){

    this.box.getButtonName().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {

        this.box.hide();
        this.getViewName().hide();
    }
    });

    } else {


    this.callToMethodA();

    }

}
```

When the button gets clicked, tempCheck boolean variable becomes true.

> tempCheck = true;

but if condition is getting failed, it always go into else part.

> If(tempCheck)

why this is happening? is this because of how java managed closures?
Note : If condition has to be outside the block as  this.callToMethodA() is used by other click handlers too.

Comment: if I'm not wrong you want to hide the box/view after the button is clicked, correct?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `addClickHandler()`, it creates the handler and immediately continues with the next statement (which is `If(tempCheck)` in this case). It does not wait for the button to be clicked, as you seem to assume. So `tempCheck` will always be false at this point.

Any code you want executed after the button is clicked has to go inside the `onClick()` method, or inside a method that you call from `onClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of thinking about Event Handling is wrong.....You have to write the functionality "in side the `onClick()` itself,whichever you want to execute when you click the close button.
 But here what you are doing is just changing one variable value...you are not doing the functionality you want to do inside the `onClick()`
I hope u understand....Even if u didn't understand this....think once...you can come to know your silly mistake...